# Can a link on a site open an Android app?

Tags: javascript, android, html

Can I set a link on my site so it will open certain Android app when clicked?

Comment: If there is an app to do so. For example, links to Reddit may open in a Reddit app, links to Youtube may open the Youtube app, etc.

Answer (score 3):

This depends on whether or not the app you want to open is capable of handling a link. If the app has an appropriate [`<intent-filter>`](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html) then it could be launched through a link. For example, the Google Play app has a filter for all play.google.com links, and gives the user an option to choose between the browser and Google Play when the linked is clicked.

Comment: How can I know if it does have?

Comment: @Dokkat what app are you trying to open?

Comment: Sales Driver by Running, I think, brazilian.

Comment: Ask the developer(s) of the app. If you can present a good use case, they might add it on your request. It's not hard to implement.

Comment: This is possibly a little out of reach. Is this the only alternative? That is, if they refuse adding the <intent-filter> to the app, can I do it myself, or is there another way to do it?

Comment: That's not possible, sorry. Only the developer of the app can add the functionality.

Comment: But again, is there a way I can see if there is an <intent-filter> already?

Comment: You *could* decompile their app's manifest and take a peek if they have one. However, if they haven't publicized its existence, it's meant for only internal use, and you might not be able to make it work without some specific request style on your part. Also, decompiling the app would violate a bunch of laws. So you'd be better of asking them.

Comment: Can I make an App that will launch another App, so I'd have an <intent-filter> on that App and it would launch the other App ? Note: I'm going to accept your answer, but might I ask you to add the information on this conversation there?

Comment: Just to confirm, you mean even without having the <intent-filter> of the app, right?

Comment: Yes. When you have your app launched by the link, your app can use an Intent to launch the other app. THe other app doesn't need to have an intent filter to handle it.